# Ubuntu 14.04 too slow and laggy!

Tags: 14.04, lenovo, ram, swap

I have Lenovo  Ideapad y510p and have dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 with Windows 8.1 and I uses Ubuntu for all my work specially for developing Android apps, I have 8GB of RAM and 9GB for swap, but it's so laggy specially when running Chrome, Android Studio and Genymotion emulator at the same time, i need those together, Also after the lag it's stuck and i can't do anything so i click on the laptop power button to force shut down it!

So what to do now?

Thanks!

This is output of: `lspci -k | egrep 'VGA|3D' -A2`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3801
    Kernel driver in use: i915

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 755M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3801
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | egrep 'VGA|3D'` terminal command there.

Comment: I am sorry, missed some. Please do it again with `lspci -k | egrep 'VGA|3D' -A2`. I need to see, which video drivers are installed.

Comment: [Genymotion is known to be a resource hog](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=173232), but even so your Ubuntu shouldn't be so slow and laggy.

Comment: Actually that what i'n shocked from, because i have a big ram and swap and awesome cpu, but it's everytime stuck and force me to power of with the hard button!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a hybrid Intel+Nvidia graphics system.

Open source driver `nouveau` is installed for Nvidia, that is not great for your adapter.

You can install a proprietary driver by running

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 nvidia-prime
```

And reboot.

Also newer driver can be installed this way

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-prime
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

After that you will be able to switch Intel and Nvidia adapters in Nvidia control panel.

Also [Bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee) is an option, but it is incompatible with nvidia-prime. You will have to choose.

Comment: So what to install now, first command `nvidia-prime` or the newer drivers or both?

Comment: You can try first one. It should work OK. If not, then other options can be used.